# How to run shell script in crontab?

Tags: shell

I have a file named `restart.sh`. The file contains 3 lines like:

```
echo 'HI'
service wildfly restart
echo 'Hello'
```

When I execute this as `> sh /bin/restart.sh` it works fine. 
When I execute this from a `cron` job, only `echo` statements are working. I'm not able to execute the file in `cron`

Answer (score 4):

Make the file executable and use the full path to the `service` binary e.g.:

```
/usr/sbin/service wildfly restart
```

Note that only `root` can run `service`, so you should add this to `root`'s `crontab` or make `sudo` password-less for this command only. Also `echo` is useless in a `cron` unless intentional to redirect STDOUT to a file.